# Get confused with summation

Tags: summation, algorithms, summation-method

I just read a paper in which the authors used summation notation in several different ways. At first, I thought that my knowledge of the formula is inadequate. So, I reviewed the basics in [here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/summation.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). Nonetheless, I'm still confused with the way they presented the formulas. 
The problem is that when I simulated the paper I found that some of the summations - as they used - are wrong and do not produce the desired results.
I put some that notations here to be checked if they present same idea or there are some type of errors with them.

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The first summation that is appearing has the same $j$ both for the $w_{ij}$ on the LHS and the dummy variable of the $\sum_j$ on the RHS, I'd say. I guess there is a typo; perhaps they should be $\sum_k$ and $c_k$ below the fraction line.